# Google Chrome won't apply injected code from self-built extension on some websites until scroll wheel turned

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created two Chrome extensions with the purpose of applying CSS and SVG filters over any web page, code viewable here:

CB Corrector (modifies colours on site to assist colour-blind people)
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hvJIn3kPAMjaIWrAiUtIEVkEesQ1ce6W

CB Simulator (simulates colour blindnesses to aid amateur web developers)
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_aHgNsLL2jam0pxmh7WuPSbIWBzIEjq0

While the two extensions have different purposes, their implementation is similar:

- button click makes popup.js send message to background.js
- background.js injects code (inserting div, style and/or svg elements) or removes injected code based upon sent message

For some reason, there is a discrepancy between CB Corrector and CB Simulator: when switching between filters in the former, the change is always instantaneous; with the latter, on some websites such as Facebook, the viewport waits until the website is scrolled with the middle wheel button.

Both extensions change the page's source code as soon as the button is pressed, and the delay in implementation only occurs for CB Simulator.

If you have any knowledge of why this may be happening, please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a SVG element and adding a whole SVG string to its innerHTML property. This will create an element like this:

```html
<svg id="insertedSVG">
   <svg width="0" height="0"></svg>
</svg>
```

I loaded your extension in Firefox and it seems that this browser is able to access the SVG element without a `<object>` tag as a wrapper.
You can read more about embedding SVG in HTML documents [here](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SVG_in_HTML).

The solution is to wrap the SVG elements in a `<object>` tag, thus Chrome will be able to access the SVG components.

```js
var insertSVG = document.createElement('object');
```

Output:

```html
<object id="insertedSVG">
   <svg width="0" height="0"></svg>
</object>
```

*Obs: remove the background `persistent` key in your `manifest.json`, because this feature will be dropped in manifest v3. It also needs to be removed if you want your extension to work in Firefox.*